# xfce-terminal: Ctrl-Shift-V pastes, but can't copy

Tags: clipboard, xfce, xfce4-terminal

Suddenly, out of the blue, my xfce4-terminal refuses to copy to the clipboard. I can paste to the terminal from the menu or with Ctrl-Shift-V, but selecting something from the terminal and then trying to copy it either from the menu or via Ctrl-Shift-C does nothing (existing clipboard content is unaffected). Other applications (like Mousepad) allow copy and paste with no problems. I was trying to copy Let's Encrypt challenge strings, but the only way I could do it was from the Terminal menu with Save Contents, then open the saved file with Mousepad and copy them from there. Ctrl-shift-C used to work the last time I needed to do it (a few days ago). Does anyone have any idea what might have happened?

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Can't copy anything from xfce4-terminal no matter what.